# Remotely control android device

Tags: android, desktop, remote-connection

I am trying to build Airdroid-like app.
I'm aware it could be big challenge but that is best way to learn, right :)

Idea is to create to two applications: one for android device and one for desktop device. Desktop application (when saying desktop, it could be also web app) would be used to "control" android device, when paired with android application, you will be able to send messages (SMS) from desktop, check all contacts (maybe even make a call), browse through files, etc. So, basically give opportunity to remotely connect to android device via desktop.
Android app would be used just to allow connection from desktop.

What I would like to ask from you is some guidelines what to look for.
How to connect those two devices? For the beginning I would like to maybe start with both devices being connected to same WiFi, so something like http server could be used? I am not sure how does this work I just come across on that in one very old tutorial for connecting two devices.

How to give commands what action to take on android device?
Is there any way to give all necessary permissions upon establishment of connection rather then asking permission for action when it is taken?

Any idea/suggestion would be really helpful and appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I have used this kind of remote control in my app with the use of amazon chime sdk. I am simply passing co-ordinates from app side to desktop through data messages(Service provided by chime) and triggering those events on desktop side.